# socks 5 danted proxy server on centos 7 not open any site

Tags: proxy, socks, dante

I have a VPS with Centos 7 os
I have installed danted script

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/Lozy/danted/master/install.sh -O install.sh 
bash install.sh
```

source : https://github.com/Lozy/danted

but when I test it by proxifier.

```
[23:14] Starting: Test 1: Connection to the Proxy Server
[23:14] IP Address: 95.216.149.37
[23:14] Connection established
[23:14] Test passed.
[23:14] Starting: Test 2: Connection through the Proxy Server
[23:49] Error : connection to the proxy server was closed unexpectedly.
    Please make sure that the proxy server protocol and address are correct.
[23:49] Test failed.
[23:49] Testing Finished.
```

test step 2 failed
i have done every thing but nothing come to my mind to fix it.

> ip: 95.216.149.37 port : 443 user: moh pass: Setaya12